# Case sensitive filter, or helper column formula that also accepts wildcards

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, string

Say I have a list containing the strings

ABC123

abc123x3

Abc123x4

ABC123x5

I want to filter the list to contain anything containing `*c1*x*` where * represents any number of characters.  i.e. I would get the 2 and 3 but not 1 and 4.

Filtering is not case sensitive.  Neither is a =COUNTIF(REF,"*c1*x") helper column.

EXACT and FIND both don't allow wildcards and SEARCH isn't case sensitive.

I guess could use a workaround using a series of SUBSTITUTES to put something in place of uppercase letters, and then filter that list, but seems like there should be a more straightforward way than that.

No answers requiring 3rd party add-ons please.

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **C**, in **D2** enter:

```
=AND(RIGHT(C2,1)="x",NOT(ISERROR(FIND("c1",C2))))
```

and copy down:

[image]

and use column **D** for filtering.

Comment: thanks, this relies on x being at the end of the string, which in my general case I won't always have.  I tried to make up some strings to illustrate the problem, but I was accidentally a little too restrictive.  Still, plus1 for using and() with multiple   not(iserror(find())) functions to work almost like wildcards.  In my specific case that will get the job done fine, as I don't have strings appearing in the wrong order in my data.  I'll leave the question open though, as a true wildcard search would, in general, be better.

Comment: @Some_Guy  Do you want the lower case ***x*** to **follow** the ***c1*** or can it be **anywhere** in the string ??

Comment: in my case this time it doesn't matter, so your method of anding finds works, but in general, I'd want it to preserve the order